# How to end all outstanding objections in OVM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am in run phase and lets say I have raised 20 objections. I want to end all these 20 objections already raised and raise 20 new objections in the same phase without jumping to the next phase. Can someone please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Your title says `OVM` yet you tagged `uvm`. Their mechanisms are slightly different

Comment: Sorry. I did not get a good tag for OVM. Can you please help me out with OVM?

Comment: You're going to need to explain more about how you are raising and dropping these objections. Why wouldn't you raise the 20 new objections first, then drop the old ones next? An objection is just a counter.

Comment: i guess you need to keep a list of raised objections, then raise new objections and drop old one by one, updating the list with new objections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is first method(you don't know how many objections were raised):

```
  phase.raise_objection(this);
  phase.raise_objection(this);
  //your code here
  m_phase.drop_objection(this, "", m_phase.get_objection_count(this));
```

Here is same method (assuming you know how many objections were raised):

```
  phase.raise_objection(this, "raise 3 objections", 3);
  //your code here
  m_phase.drop_objection(this, "drop 3 objections", 3);
  end
```

Less clever method, but worth mentioning:

```
  `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("Dropping all objections now"), UVM_MEDIUM)  
  for (int i=0 ; m_phase.get_objection_count(this) > 0; i++) begin
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("Dropping objection #%d", i), UVM_MEDIUM)
    m_phase.drop_objection(this);
  end
```

You can find more information about uvm_phase class here:
https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/base/uvm_phase-svh.html

I also coded these examples for you to try here:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2KLd